# Some Simple Algebra

Tags: algebra-precalculus

\begin{align*}
    x &= \frac 12 js + \frac 12 is \\\
    y &= \frac 14 is - \frac 14 js 
\end{align*}

How can I find a
\begin{align*}
    i &= \\\
    j &= 
\end{align*}
conversion of this?

Edit:

I am not happy with the moderaters assumption on my syntax.

```
x = (j * s / 2) + (i * s / 2)
y = (i * s / 4) - (j * s / 4)
```

is the proper format.

Comment: See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_of_linear_equations.

Comment: SimpleRookie, `x = (j * s / 2) + (i * s / 2)` is *exactly* the same as $x = \frac{js}{2} + \frac{is}{2}.$

Comment: Tell that to notepad.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Looking at the two equations, they look pretty damn similar. There must some relationships between $x$ and $2y$. Calculate $x+2y$ and $x-2y$:

$$x+2y=is$$
$$x-2y=js$$

And you have $i$ and $j$. It's easy to take if from here.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not a math fellow. The syntax is specific, but was edited by presumptuous moderators. As I am finding common on the stack sites. Mod's who think they know the posters intentions.

Comment: However, thank you for your awnser.